# Converting and adding variables

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble taking a variable given by `gets.chomp` and either adding it to another variable or to an integer.

```
puts 'Hello mate what is thy first name?'
name1 = gets.chomp
puts 'Your name is ' + name1 + ' eh? What is thy middle name?'
name2 = gets.chomp
puts 'What is your last name then ' + name1 + '?' 
name3 = gets.chomp
Puts 'Oh! So your full name is ' + name1 + ' ' + name2 + ' ' + name3 + ' ?'
puts 'That is lovey!'
puts 'did you know there are ' ' + name1.length.to_i + '+' + 'name2.length.to_i + '+' + name3.length.to_i + '' in your full name
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: what is the problem? You messed up with quotes in your last line, btw.

Comment: Pay attention to the syntax highlight, it reveals your syntax error.

Comment: It seems you have one extra single quote after `'did you know there are '`. Also, there is no such a method like `Puts`, it should be `puts`.

Comment: And don't use string concatenation. Use string interpolation instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to clean this up in Ruby that I'll demonstrate here:

```
puts 'Hello mate what is thy first name?'
name1 = gets.chomp

# Inline string interpolation using #{...} inside double quotes
puts "Your name is #{name1} eh? What is thy middle name?"
name2 = gets.chomp

# Interpolating a single string argument using the String#% method
puts 'What is your last name then %s?' % name1
name3 = gets.chomp

# Interpolating with an expression that includes code
puts "Oh! So your full name is #{ [ name1, name2, name3 ].join(' ') }?"
puts 'That is lovey!'

# Combining the strings and taking their aggregate length
puts 'Did you know there are %d letters in your full name?' % [
  (name1 + name2 + name3).length
]

# Using collect and inject to convert to length, then sum.
puts 'Did you know there are %d letters in your full name?' % [
  [ name1, name2, name3 ].collect(&:length).inject(:+)
]
```

The [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) method is a variant of [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) that's very convenient for this sort of formatting. It gives you a lot of control over presentation.

That last one might look a bit mind-bending but one of the powerful features of Ruby is being able to string together a series of simple transformations into something that does a lot of work.

That part would look even more concise if you used an array to store the name instead of three independent variables:

```
name = [ ]

name << gets.chomp
name << gets.chomp
name << gets.chomp

# Name components are name[0], name[1], and name[2]

# Using collect -> inject
name.collect(&:length).inject(:+)

# Using join -> length
name.join.length
```

It's generally a good idea to organize things in structures that lend themselves to easy manipulation, exchange with other methods, and are easy to persist and restore, such as from a database or a file.

Comment: brilliant, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#I think using "#{variable_name}" would be easier to achieve your goal, just
#stay away from the single quotes when using this form of string          
#interpolation.
puts "Hello mate what is thy first name?"
name1 = gets.chomp
puts "Your name is #{name1} eh? What is thy middle name?"
name2 = gets.chomp
puts "What is your last name then #{name1}?"
name3 = gets.chomp
puts "Oh! So your full name is #{name1} #{name2} #{name3}?"
puts "That is lovey!"
puts "Did you know there are '#{name1.length + name2.length + name3.length}' letters in your full name?"
```